# Entity Framework 6 performance impact with IList

Tags: entity-framework

Is there any performance impact of IList instead ICollection (or IEnumerable) in EF entities?

Comment: A little more information like why you are asking this question would be helpful. `IList` etc. are interfaces so no, there is no difference because those never execute code. What matters is how those interfaces are implemented and how they are used. Implementations of `IList` may or may not be more performant for your specific scenario than an implementation of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I saw lots of questions about that with conflicting answers. But to provide more details I'm interested in the impact the declaration of a collection as IList instead the common ICollection/IEnumerable could have in the way the EF works. More round trips to DB? More memory to manage LINQ instructions? Not at all?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how you retrieve the data from the database context. Entity framework uses **[DbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)** in order to expose an abstraction from linq to the database tables. This exposure comes in the form of an **[IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb351562%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**. IQueryable implements the IEnumerable interface and allows for queried results to the database to be enumerated.

> Enumeration forces the expression tree associated with an IQueryable object to be executed.
>   -MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb351562(v=vs.100).aspx

So depending on if you simply use a ToList() and grab the entire set, use a .Take(), or a .Skip(), or if you use a projection such as .Select() -- all of these factors weigh into how performant the entity framework will be when getting data from the database.

What you choose as far as an interface to represent the data you have fetched will not affect performance at all. This is because the interfaces only expose methods to use, but will not change the underlying set of data.

Basically the methods will range from a base of IEnumerable, all the way up to IList which has a larger selection available. In general, you can use **[IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** for a set of data which needs to be iterated and used, **[ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** for a set of data which is going to be iterated and modified, and **[IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5y536ey6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** for a set of data which is going to be iterated, modified, and sorted.

Comment: Your use of `ToList()` will impact how much memory your application uses because it will move everything that matches your LINQ into memory. When you are iterating over a large dataset only once you can minimize memory usage by not using `ToList()` and instead iterating over the `IQueryable` using `foreach`.

Comment: If you will reference data in a "small" list multiple times within your code, it can be worthwhile to use `ToList()` to cache the results to memory and work locally instead of hitting the database many times.

Comment: @JeremyCook - From your explanation I believe you are thinking about linq to objects, and not linq to entities. Using `.ToList()` on a DbSet without a take size and a where clause is generally bad practice. If `.ToList()` is used instead prior to allowing the database to handle trimming the data set then too much information will be requested and that will negatively affect performance. The remark about using ToList() isn't about memory usage, it is about how much information is being downloaded from the database while the user waits.

Comment: Totally agree. I'm just trying to mention the benefit of iterating over an `IQueryable` instead of loading all results into memory with a call like `ToList()` or `ToListAsync()`. EDIT: But using `ToList()` can be beneficial when that data is going to be accessed in memory multiple times.